Allow Internet, block vLANs with IPv6 in pfSense
How can I create a firewall rule in pfSense to allow IPv6 access to the Internet without also allowing access to IPv6 devices in other VLANs that have public IPv6 addresses?
For IPv4, I created an alias for private network ranges and created an inverse match to allow traffic to anywhere except those. I realize there are IPv6 private ranges as well and that I can include these in the alias, but what about the public IPv6 addresses assigned to devices in other VLANs?
The only thing I can think to do is to add the IPv6 prefixes for the other VLANs to that alias which would, presumably, do what I want... however, I don't know for certain that my consumer ISP won't change my IPv6 address at some point in the future and I don't want to enable access if that happens unexpectedly.
